# Specific way of plotting matrix (picture included)

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot a rather small matrix (4 by 5) as shown in the picture - please, see

[image]

(It is a short time-series of certain indicator, which consists of components w+x+y+z. For year 1, the indicator value denoted as "a" equals w_1 + x_1 + y_1 + z_1.) \

Any thoughts how to plot something like this? Maybe it's not a good idea to plot this kind of data. On the other, it's not that bad imo. And it's certainly better than let say 5 histograms or even worse, 5 pie charts. \

OT: Do you know any sites or documents with advanced R plots examples? Google has found just simple plots.

EDIT: data example (vectors w/x/y/z are already expressed a a percentage)

```
w <- (0.1,0.15,0.1,0.1,0.3)
x <- (0.15,0.15,0.1,0.1,0.25)
y <- (0.15,0.10,0.2,0.2,0.05)
z <- (0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.4)
abcd <- (222222,333333,444444,500000,555555)
```

Comment: This question would be easier to answer, if you provided example data.

Comment: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/position_stack.html

Comment: The [Lattice package](http://lmdvr.r-forge.r-project.org/figures/figures.html) can do something like this, with a little bit of effort, I believe.  mit's link isn't quite what you want, but I'd bet that ggplot2 can do that as well.

Comment: Thanks for links. I'll figure it out.

Comment: In addition to the links in other comments, here are samplers of fancy R graphics examples: [R graphics plot gallery](http://www.sr.bham.ac.uk/~ajrs/R/r-gallery.html), [R graphics gallery](http://research.stowers-institute.org/efg/R/), [R graphs gallery](http://scs.math.yorku.ca/index.php/R_Graphs_Gallery)

Comment: I think you should be using a `stacked barplot` for categorical data but your diagram is a `stacked area chart`. There must be hundreds of [r] stacked barplot questions in SO by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the picture and information you provided, I can't really tell what's going on on the righthand side of your figure, but the relative abundance plot you've shown is pretty easy to make using `geom_area` from ggplot2. Here's how to get it from the data you provide:

First, your data should be in a single dataframe in long form, which is easy to do with the reshape package. You also should add an explicit time value for each observation:

```
df<-data.frame(w,x,y,z)
library(reshape)
df<-melt(df)
df$year<-rep(c(1:5),4)
```

Now the data can easily be plotted as a relative abundance graph:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x=year,y=value,group=variable))+geom_area(aes(fill=variable))
```

Is this more or less what you're trying to do? I'm sorry if I've only partially answered or misunderstood your question- as I said, I'm still not totally sure what you're looking for from the picture.

Answer (score 0):

This seems pretty close to your graphic.

[image]

```
# your sample data
w <- c(0.1,0.15,0.1,0.1,0.3)
x <- c(0.15,0.15,0.1,0.1,0.25)
y <- c(0.15,0.10,0.2,0.2,0.05)
z <- c(0.6,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.4)
df  <- rbind(w,x,y,z)

library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
gg <- melt(df)
ggplot(gg) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=Var2, y=value, fill=Var1), stat="identity")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)+
  scale_fill_discrete("") + labs(x="Year", y="")
```

Your data is in so-called "wide format", which means the different years are in different columns. For ease of plotting, it needs to be converted to "long format" using `melt(...)`. In `gg` all the values are in one column (called `values`), and there is a new column which indicates which column it came from originally (called `Var2` here). The column `Var1` contains the original row names.

The `ggplot` calls do the following:

```
ggplot(gg)    establishes gg as the reference dataset
geom_bar(...) tells ggplot what to use for the x and y axes, and for colors
sacle_y...    tells ggplot to use percent for the y-axis tick marks
scale_fill... tells ggplot to turn off the legend label
labs(...)     tells ggplot how to label the axes.
```

Comment: Joe's suggestion above is more similar to what I was initially looking for so I accepted his answer. However, this is also very interesting way of data representation!___ What kinda bothers me though is the order of variable 1 in the legend on the right as it goes alphabetically and not like on the plot. According to http://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/03/23/ggplot2-changing-the-default-order-of-legend-labels-and-stacking-of-data/, I have to do it all manually. Btw, is it possible to change names in the legend so it doesn't affect variables' names?